# Why doesn't my struct encode in the order I declared properties and coding keys?

Tags: swift, codable

This is the main struct that encodes properly as far as when I print `print(String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) as Any)` 
the struct prints encoded with mainObject printing first then the rest of the variables in the struct but i want it to print: mainAccount, mainObject, reference in that order.

```
struct T: Codable {
    init(){}

     let mainAccount = "IMHOTECHPECOM"
     let mainObject = mainObject()
     let reference = UUID()
     // Enum that allows easy encoding
     enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
         case mainAccount, mainObject, reference;
     }
     // function to conform to encodable protocol
     func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
         var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
         try container.encode(mainAccount, forKey: .merchantAccount)
         try container.encode(mainObject.self, forKey: .mainObject)
         try container.encode(reference, forKey: .reference)
       
     }
    
     // conforms with decodable protocol
     required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
         let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
         _ = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .mainAccount)
         _ = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .mainObject)
         _ = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .reference)
         
     }
 }
```

This is the mainObject

```
struct mainObject:  Codable {
    var type = "kind"
    var identifier: String = ""
    var guide: String = ""
    
    init(){}
   
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey{
         case type, identifier, guide;
    }
    // function to conform to encodable protocol
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(type, forKey: .type)
        try container.encode(identifier, forKey: .identifier)
        try container.encode(guide, forKey: .guide)
        }
    // conforms with decodable protocol
   required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
       identifier = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .identifier)
       guide = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .identifier) 
     
    }
}
```

This is the function in the actual view encoding the data from a button press

```
func getBalance() async {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = [.sortedKeys]
        encoder.outputFormatting = [.withoutEscapingSlashes]
        encoder.outputFormatting = [.prettyPrinted]
        
        guard let encoded = try? encoder.encode(mainobject) else {
            print("Failed to encode")
            return
        }
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://testurl.com")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        
        do {
            let (response, _) = try await URLSession.shared.upload(for: request, from: encoded)
            print(String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) as Any)
            print(String(data: response, encoding: .utf8) as Any)
            } catch {
            print("Encoding failed")
        }
  
        let _ = try? JSONDecoder().decode(mainObject.self, from: encoded)
```

Comment: A small detail: you are referring to structs but don’t actually have any in your code — you have classes, which are quite different in Swift.

Comment: @jnpdx I changed the classes to structs that was accidental

Comment: In this case rob mayoff's answer will work, but keep in mind that the JSON format does not promise key order in objects. If you're relying on that, it's not defined behavior, and different JSON implementations are free to order things differently (and do). If you need order, you should be use JSON arrays. That said, if you need more an encoder that does support key-order, RNJSON is highly experimental, but shows how to do it. https://github.com/rnapier/RNJSON

Comment: Unrelated to the issue but it's pointless to *prettyPrint* anything which is sent to a server. The server doesn't care at all. And actually the server shouldn't care about the order of a dictionary either because the value of a dictionary is retrieved by key rather than by index.

Comment: Either way none of the output formatting doesn't apply to the console so why may that be the case @vadian

Comment: Does order matter to send to send POST request to API server? @RobNapier everything encodes correctly with my code, although the output formatting does nothing when printing the encoder to console

Comment: Order matters if a consuming service (incorrectly) relies on order. If the service is written correctly and does not rely on order, then it doesn't matter. This has nothing to do with how the JSON is sent (i.e. "POST request" or any other way). Some services rely on JSON being provided in the same order JavaScript encodes it. This is wrong (or at least unportable), but it happens sometimes. If you're not certain, assume that the server is written correctly, and don't mess with what Swift does.

Comment: Ok so since that is the case, output formatting doesn't work, which would enable the correct order do you know why that is the case? @RobNapier

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Why is what the case? What do you mean "output formatting doesn't work?" Generally formatting is irrelevant when posting requests. I suspect have an unrelated bug.

Comment: The 3 lines in the beginning of the only function ```let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.outputFormatting = [.sortedKeys]
        encoder.outputFormatting = [.withoutEscapingSlashes]
        encoder.outputFormatting = [.prettyPrinted] ``` does not print formatted although there is no errors with syntax @RobNapier

Comment: That keeps changing the settings; you mean `encoder.outputFormatting = [.sortedKeys, .withoutEscapingSlashes, .pretttyPrinted]`. When I clean up the various syntax errors so the above code will compile, it pretty prints as expected (since that's the last setting applied). Can you provide a working example (one that we can compile ourselves) of what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, the order you're asking for happens to match alphabetical order. So if you add `.sortedKeys` to your encoder's `outputFormatting` property, you'll get the order you want:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder() 
encoder.outputFormatting = [.sortedKeys]
let data = try encoder.encode(myT)
```

This will affect the order of keys in all objects in the JSON. So your `T`'s keys will be output in the order `mainAccount, mainObject, reference`, and your `mainObject`'s keys will be output in the order `guide, identifier, type`.

The general answer is that `JSONEncoder` doesn't remember the order  in which you add keys to a keyed container. Internally, [it uses a standard Swift `Dictionary` to store the keys and values](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/efedfc30e7ea2ce5e4db85e3869b9cb149273ad9/Sources/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L296). A Swift `Dictionary` doesn't guarantee any ordering of its keys, and the order can change each time your program is started.

If you want to guarantee that the order of your keys is preserved, you'll have to write your own `Encoder` implementation, which is not a trivial task.